# Does users of PWS have the role of Admin?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I want to know if when you create an account in Pivotal you have the role of an Admin.

Here are the roles according to cloud foundry documentation https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your link:

> Admin is a user role that has been assigned the cloud_controller.admin scope in UAA. An admin user has permissions on all orgs and spaces and can perform operational actions using the Cloud Controller API. To create an account with cloud_controller.admin scope for your installation, see the Create an Admin User topic.

There are **no** users of PWS that are given admin access.  That is reserved for the Pivotal employees that run & manage PWS.  For security reasons, this is a very small number of people.

As Josh mentioned, when you get an org on PWS you'll be given full control over your org so you can do anything you want within the scope of your org.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just one last quastion, what does UAA stand for ?

Comment: User Account & Authorization Server -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/

Comment: @DanielMikusa Can we create service broker using Cloud Foundry CLI commands on PWS?

Comment: You can create brokers that are scoped to your space only.  This only requires the SpaceDev role and not platform admin.  Users outside of your space won't see that broker through.  You need platform admin to create global brokers.   See here -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/managing-service-brokers.html#register-broker

Answer (score 0):

When you create an account, you will be `OrgManager` of the org that is created for you, as well as `SpaceManager` and `SpaceDeveloper` of the default space created.